# k in zoo's rollmean/rollmedian using floor_date

Tags: r, zoo

Using code like this:

```
temp <- something %>%
    group_by(
        date = floor_date(some_date, unit = "month")
        ,some_category
    ) %>%
    summarise(
        n = n_distinct(id)
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        rollmean = rollmean(n, k=3, fill = NA) 
        , rollmedian = rollmedian(n, k=3, fill = NA) 
    )
```

What does the k mean in my sceanrio? 3 months or 3 days?

Btw, I do not think this works when I used some_category in the group_by. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It means take the mean of the k points centered at the current point.  rollmean(n, 3, fill = NA) is computed as: c(NA, mean(n[1:3]), mean(n[2:4]), ...)    See ?rollmean

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag when posting.